# How can I get my site to show again in Google?

Tags: google

The site in reference is a client site and I do not want to mention it, so I'll use the made up FooBar for this example.

The other day, if you searched for `FooBar` Google would show you the website for `foobar.com` as the first result. Now, if you search `FooBar` Google asks: **"Did you mean foo bar?"** and doesn't show any results.

I know the site is still indexed because if I search for "FooBar" (with quotes) I see it, plus a lot of other results for the site.

The day before I submitted a sitemap.xml file and since then it's borked. According to Google Webmaster Tools there's nothing wrong with the sitemap, and there are no errors on the site; it's clean and is performing well.

Why did this happen and how to I fix it?

Edit: this site has been online for almost a year, so it's not like Google doesn't know about it.

Answer (score -1):

try improving your Search Engine Optimization, maybe you could start by adding alt tags to your images, checking on sites behavior on a mobile view I would suggest you jump online and start looking at your competitors sites as well

Comment: This is very general advice and not all that relevant to this particular problem.     When answering here, please try to link to references or tell stories from your personal experience that illustrate why your suggestions might work.